# How to calculate DataGridView.Rows.Height?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to calculate dgv.Rows.Height

```
int x = dgv1.Rows.Height
```

Rows.Height or dgv1.RowsHeight does not exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Row heights can vary, so try the row you want:

```
int x = dgv1.Rows[0].Height;
```

Alternatively, I think it's also available from the template:

```
int x = dgv1.RowTemplate.Height;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want the combined height of the column header and all the rows, try:

```
int x = dgv1.ColumnHeadersHeight + dgv1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(r => r.Height);
```

Comment: Nice and elegant!

Comment: small comment: if the view needs scrollbar it is too small with the above calculation. you need to add the scrollbar too.

Answer (score 0):

To resise the datagrid view to fit the number of rows (no scrollbar needed), use

```
dgv.height=dgv.ColumnHeadersHeight+dgv.Rows.Count * dgv.RowTemplate.Height+2
```

If your row heights are not fixed then replace "dgv.Rows.count" with the sum of the row heights